# Return the count of rows grouped by week MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get the row count from a MySQL table where the data is grouped by WEEK.

So far the query I have is:

```
 "SELECT count(*) as tweets, twitTimeExtracted as date 
  FROM scene.twitData 
  group by week(twitTimeExtracted)"
```

This query returns the data below:

[image]

As you can see, the weeks are not correct, I'm expecting data for each week starting with Monday 7th January (7,14,21,28,4,11 etc...) and running through to this week.

I also tried a modified version of the orignal query:

```
SELECT count(*) as tweets, twitTimeExtracted as date 
FROM scene.twitData 
WHERE date(twitTimeExtracted) 
   BETWEEN '2013-01-07' and '2013-03-11' 
group by week(twitTimeExtracted)
```

This returns similar results as the first query.

Maybe there is an inconsistency with some data stored in the DATETIME: twitTimeExtracted column on a few rows of data? I don't really know I'm not very experienced with MySQL.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So, what week number was Monday 7th January? What week number was Monday 1st January? Maybe try: "group by week(twitTimeExtracted,1)"

Comment: _how_ is this incorrect? Do you expect a magical begin-of-week-date to appear? (BTW, I'd group on `YEAR()` too..)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This converts the `datetime` value to the appropriate Monday of the week

```
select count(*) as tweets,
       str_to_date(concat(yearweek(twitTimeExtracted), ' monday'), '%X%V %W') as `date`
from twitData 
group by yearweek(twitTimeExtracted)
```

[`yearweek`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) returns both week and year. Together with the string `monday`, [`str_to_date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) gives you the Monday's `datetime` value.

If your week starts on [Monday](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/days/#monday), use `yearweek(twitTimeExtracted, 1)` instead.

Comment: Doesn't this fail when dates are from different years?

Comment: @NateS I don't think so. `yearweek` delivers both year *and* week, so it should work, even if you have multiple years in your dataset. Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

One option to always get the Monday of the week is to use adddate:

```
SELECT count(*) as tweets, adddate(twitTimeExtracted, INTERVAL 2-DAYOFWEEK(twitTimeExtracted) DAY)
FROM twitData 
WHERE date(twitTimeExtracted) 
   BETWEEN '2013-01-07' and '2013-03-11' 
GROUP BY adddate(twitTimeExtracted, INTERVAL 2-DAYOFWEEK(twitTimeExtracted) DAY)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e680/1)

Comment: thanks, this query produces ~19,000 rows of results. the results per week aren't condensed to one result row count.

Comment: @user1814487 -- not sure why, did you see the SQL Fiddle?  Not as expected?

Comment: The SQL fiddle works as expected I believe however when I run the query on my server I'm getting all the results from the week returned with the date as the first day of the month and the time and a 1 in the count(*) column: for example http://i.imgur.com/kMMIAel.png

Comment: the dates are correct now though starting with Monday 7th January (7,14,21,28,4,11 etc...)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 SELECT count(*) as tweets, 
     date_add('7 Jan 2012', day, datediff('7 Jan 2012', twitTimeExtracted)) % 7   
 FROM scene.twitData 
 group by date_add('7 Jan 2012', day, datediff('7 Jan 2012', twitTimeExtracted)) % 7
```

Comment: thanks but this kicks up errors: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'day, datediff('7 Jan 2012', twitTimeExtracted)) Mod 7   
 FROM scene.twitData 
' at line 2"

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution:

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(yourDate, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(yourDate) DAY));
```

Eg:

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(DATE("2016-04-11"), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(DATE("2016-04-11")) DAY));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
select 
DATE_ADD(DATE(date), INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK(date)) DAY) as weekend,
count(tweets)
from scene.twitData 
  group by weekend;
```